# Remote git branches not showing up in IDE

Tags: git, ide, atom-editor, adobe-brackets

I've looked at [adobe-brackets](/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets) and [atom-editor](/questions/tagged/atom-editor), the remote branches don't show up in the side panel when choosing to switch to them. They show up if I choose to pull from another branch. I tried `git fetch --all` and several other commands, the branches show up when listing them, just not in the side pane here. (Or in Atom). I've noticed that if I create a new branch and use the same branch as the origin that it seems to work but this seems like a dirty hack and I'm not sure that it's the correct way to do it.

[image: Visual Summary of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected. Usually a git GUI only lists the branches existing in your local repo, not all the branches existing in the remote repo.

A remote branch is just that, a remote branch. While you can check it out, you don't want to work on a remote branch directly (i.e. commit to it directly). Rather, you want to create a local branch tracking it, and work on the local branch - just like how you did to make it "work". It's not a dirty hack. Welcome to the club of normal git users. :-)